# Image Component declaring source dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This might be a potential bug in the Image component for react native:

```
//1. Works as expected
render() {
   return (
     <View>
         <Image source={require('../images/somepic.jpg')}
             resizeMode='contain'
             style={{width: 600, height: 600}}
             />
     </View>
   );
}


//2. Does not work:
render() {
   var imageLocation = '../images/somepic.jpg';
   return (
     <View>
         <Image source={require(imageLocation)}
             resizeMode='contain'
             style={{width: 600, height: 600}}
             />
     </View>
   );
}
```

In the second example the error displayed is: Requiring unknown module "../images/somepic.jpg". If you are sure there is a module there, try restarting the package or running "npm install"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The documentation does not recommend this way

The [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html) of react native declares this way, using a variable, as *BAD*.

```
// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />
```

The following patterns are suggested:

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />


// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active ? require('./my-icon-active.png') : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />
```